# Sequences and Series in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

My Prof mentioned that about 95% of the results we have learned about sequences have implications about series. What are some examples of common results (or rules I guess) about sequences that don't end up having consequences about series and why?

Comment: A series is just a sequence of partial sums. What do your results say, given this definition?

Comment: I think the correct answer here is "there are no such examples," because sequences are equivalent to series. This is very concrete: every sequence $a_1,\ldots$ corresponds to a series whose $n$-th partial sum is $a_n$, and every series corresponds to a sequence of partial sums. In fact, this is just the *definition* of a series.

Comment: More interesting is to ask your prof about that %5 for which result for series cannot be applied to sequences and tell us.

Comment: @zkutch You mean like if $a_n$ is strictly decreasing and bounded, then $\langle a_n\rangle$ must converge to a limit, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\sum_{k=1}^n a_n\right]$ might not exist?  Something like $a_n = (1/n)$?  Alternatively, what about the convergent sequence $a_n = 1?$

Comment: @user2661923. Exact translating is taking $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=S_n$  strictly decreasing and bounded, which not leaves ambiguities. As mentioned others (William, Elliot G) there is not fact about one, that cannot be translated to another, but, may be, mentioned prof can surprise us.

Comment: @zkutch The professor wasn't talking to mathematicians, but to unsophisticated students.  The professor was probably experienced enough to understand how the students would view sequences and series as disconnected ideas.  When I first was introduced to these ideas, this is how I saw it.

Comment: @user2661923. How do we know with who the conversation was? And why talk about 95% when you can say 100% and it will be true? let's see what answers OP, if answers.

Comment: @zkutch The OP is a student.  He heard the professor speaking.  Isn't it natural to assume that the professor was speaking to his class?  Further, while it is ordinarily a good idea to ask for a reaction from the OP, remember that it is the OP who is confused about the concepts, in the first place.

Comment: @user2661923. If you read carefully my very first comment, then I asked OP to ask prof.